# SQL Server 2008 view and Entity Framework 4

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, stored-procedures, view

I'm using EF4 to retrieve database objects. I have defined a view which sums up information on users.

In SSMS, I get 8 different results using `select *` or stored procedure. 
Example:

[image]

When querying in EF4, my view returns 8 results, but property `UserTeamName` is always returned as the first value `(BoboTeam)`. This is strange because `UserRole` is returned correctly, the difference between these items is that `UserTeamName` is nullable.

It seems like a problem with EF, since the object is filled by the `ExecuteFunction` method from `System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext`:

```
public ObjectResult<MySecurityView> SecurityList(Nullable<global::System.Int32> userId)
    {
        ObjectParameter userIdParameter;
        if (userId.HasValue)
        {
            userIdParameter = new ObjectParameter("userId", userId);
        }
        else
        {
            userIdParameter = new ObjectParameter("userId", typeof(global::System.Int32));
        }

        return base.ExecuteFunction<MySecurityView>("SecurityList", userIdParameter);
    }
```

Same result when we use a linqtosql request instead of a stored procedure. Any hint is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF requires that each returned record is uniquely identifiable. When you add SQL view to entity model it by default takes all non-nullable columns and defines them as a key. So in your case it selected `UserRole` and `UserId` as entity key.

Another internal rule of EF can track each entity key only once. So when it loads record with Role=Manager and Id=1 it adds it to its internal identity map. Once it loads record with the same key again it will not create a new instance of the entity but use the already loaded one (which has TeamName=Bobo Team). That is why you have all team names set to Bobo Team. Only first record in the pair is used.

Try to manually configure entity key in EDMX to involve UserTeamName.

Comment: Thanks for response, when I set the team property as an entity key it works but must be a non-nullable value, not what I want, It seems I can't do this. I delete all columns which were nullable and now it works fine, thanks a lot for help you gave me